# vsts - restrict access to create items on “Epic” and “Feature” level

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to restrict access to create features/epics in VSTS online for everyone except a certain group/user in a specific project?

We want only certain users to be able to create new ones.

Answer (score 0):

No. If a user can create work items, they can create any type of work item.

If you want to remove the ability for *any* user to create a certain type of work item in a particular team project, you can modify the process template and disable that work item type.